# LINQ how to select the newest folder according to creation date

Tags: c#, linq

```
 DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path)
 DirectoryInfo[] directoryInfos = dInfo.GetDirectories();
```

How can i iterate directoryInfos and select the newest folder?

am looking for the NAME of the newest folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two ways - not sure which is the 'best':

```
var newest1 = directoryInfos.FirstOrDefault(di => di.CreationTime == directoryInfos.Max(d => d.CreationTime));
```

or

```
var newest2 = directoryInfos.OrderByDescending(di => di.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: second will be faster as its will not iterate over and over for max creation time as in first one

Comment: But it still has to iterate over all directory infos to sort them, so they are probably very similar in terms of performance I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime DD = directoryInfos.Max(x=> x.CreationTime);

string[] ss =  directoryInfos.Where(x=> x.CreationTime == DD).Select(x=> x.Name).ToArray();
```

array because there can be more than 1 folder having same latest creationtime

Comment: i am looking for the folder name

Comment: `v` will be a `DirectoryInfo` instance, so just do `v.Name`.

Comment: v is a 'DateTime' object and not 'DirectoryInfo'

Comment: Thats what i wrote in samjudson answer

Comment: Nikhil Agrawal - so how can i get the folder's name?

Answer (score 0):

var folder = (from d in directoryInfos orderby d.CreationTime descending select d).First();

but the other answers are of course faster :)